# Flagging options for a question are hidden with Android browser

Tags: bug, mobile-web, flag-dialog

When I try to flag a question on Stackoverflow from my Android phone (Google Nexus 4) with the Chrome browser (up-to-date), the textarea to add an answer is displayed above the "flag" box.

It only happens if the question have no answer yet.

See these examples :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you it work for you in the past?  I have definitely flagged posted with Android before using the Chrome browser, but the UX is not ideal as it involves a lot of scrolling.  I don't remember every seeing that textbox come up over top of the dialog.

Comment: +1 status repro'd here. I'm on Android 4.2 / 4.3 (unsure which). It looks like the answer text box is being displayed on top of the close dialog.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I don't remember using this feature before, without this problem.